# Facebook registration 500 error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-oauth

I am implementing a Facebook registration page for my site using iframe, as follows:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?
             client_id=<%= FACEBOOK_CONFIG['app_id'].to_s %>&
             redirect_uri=<%= FULL_ROOT.to_s %>&
             fields=name,first_name,last_name,gender,email"
        scrolling="auto"
        frameborder="no"
        style="border:none"
        allowTransparency="true"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        data-scope="email">
</iframe>
```

I am using rails.

When the user clicks on register, he is redirected to the correct page UNLESS I include his email and birthdate, in which case I get:

```
Request URL:https://www.facebook.com/ajax/connect/registration_widget.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 OK
Request Headersview source
:host:www.facebook.com
:method:POST
:path:/ajax/connect/registration_widget.php
:scheme:https
:version:HTTP/1.1
accept:*/*
accept-encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8
content-length:758
content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
etc.
```

Clearly this has to do with the fact that the user's birthday and email aren't part of his public profile.

i tried requesting these permissions (Added them to my app settings on Facebook) but nothing works.

I need to crack this: how can I register the user, including his e-mail and birthday?

Thanks!

Comment: Requesting email and birthday in the Registration plugin has nothing to do with app permissions. File a bug with Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to have been a Facebook bug that was resolved yesterday.

Still hoping for my $500!